# dynamic indivdual word autocomplete python3

Tags: python-3.x, autocomplete, prompt

I am looking to make a autocomplete based on index, so each argument has its own autocomplete for example

PROMPT> use stackoverflow

therefore use would have its own autocomplete and so would stackoverflow
I know this is possible as empire did it and ive tried things like readline, prompt_toolkit and suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be completed with the cmd module take a look

```
class CmdTemplate(cmd.Cmd):

    def __init__(self, wordlist, prompt):
        self.wordlist = wordlist
        self.prompt = prompt
        super(CmdTemplate, self).__init__()


    def do_c2(self, line):
        pass


    def complete_c2(self, text, line, start_index, end_index):
        if text:
            return [
                words for words in wordlist
                if words.startswith(text)
            ]
        else:
            return wordlist
```

do_ means the main command and complete_ autocompletes it, good luck